# How to deinit ViewModel with combine framework when views disappears

Tags: swiftui, state, viewmodel, combine, deinit

I use Combine in viewModels to update the views. But if I store the AnyCancellable objects into a set of AnyCancellable, the deinit method is never called. I use the deinit to cancel all cancellables objects.

```
struct View1: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel:ViewTextModel = ViewTextModel()
    @Injected var appActions:AppActions

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.viewModel.viewText)

            Button(action: {
                self.appActions.goToView2()
            }) {
                Text("Go to view \(self.viewModel.viewText)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class ViewTextModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var viewText: String

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(state:AppState) {
        // initial state
        viewText = "view  \(state.view)"
        // updated state
        state.$view.removeDuplicates().map{ "view \($0)"}.assign(to: \.viewText, on: self).store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    deinit {
        cancellables.forEach { $0.cancel() }
    } 
}
```

Each time the view is rebuilt, a new viewmodel is instantiated but the old one is not destroyed. `viewText` attribute is updated on each instance with `state.$view.removeDuplicates().map{ "view \($0)"}.assign(to: \.viewText, on: self).store(in: &cancellables)`

If I don't store the cancellable object in the set, `deinit` is called but `viewText` is not updated if the state's changed for the current view.

Do you have an idea of ​​how to manage the update of the state without multiplying the instances of the viewmodel ?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting, I have the same problem (`deinit` not called) and I'm using `sink` (not `assign`).

Comment: My problem turned to be a memory leak in the view: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59303789/swiftui-memory-leak-when-referencing-property-from-closure-inside-form-navigatio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sink` instead of `assign`:

```
state.$view
    .removeDuplicates()
    .sink { [weak self] in self?.viewText = $0 }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

But I question the need for Combine here at all. Just use a computed property:

```
class ViewTextModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var state: AppState

    var viewText: String { "view \(state.view)" }
}
```

## UPDATE

If your deployment target is iOS 14 (or macOS 11) or later:

Because you are storing to an `@Published`, you can use the [`assign(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/assign(to:)) operator instead. It manages the subscription for you without returning an `AnyCancellable`.

```
state.$view
    .removeDuplicates()
    .map { "view \($0)" }
    .assign(to: &$viewText)
    // returns Void, so nothing to store
```

Comment: Using ```sink``` instead of ```assign``` solves my problem thanks. The example here is deliberately simple to explain my problem. I prefer to use a viewmodel to prepare the data according to the state of the application.

Comment: assign(to:on:) returns an AnyCancellable..

Comment: Yes, `assign(to:on:)` returns an `AnyCancellable`, which you then have to somehow store without creating a retain cycle. That was the problem with the code in the original question.