# How do you fix a SwiftUI memory leak caused by compound modifiers + animation?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I fix a memory leak which happens when I use compound modifiers with an animation?

In this example we have 4 `MySquareView` squares that have an animated rotation effect, and these sit within a ZStack in `ContentView` which has a scale modifier. As you can see the memory in use continues to increase over time.

[image]
[image: memory leak]

The same issue seems to happen with other modifiers too. Full example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MySquare: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var offsetX: CGFloat
    var offsetY: CGFloat
}

struct MySquareView: View {
    @State private var rotateSquare = true
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.purple)
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(self.rotateSquare ? -25 : 25))
            .onAppear(perform: {
                withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                    self.rotateSquare.toggle()
                }
            })
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {


    var mySquares = [
        MySquare(offsetX: -40, offsetY: 40),
        MySquare(offsetX: 50, offsetY: -20),
        MySquare(offsetX: -10, offsetY: 80),
        MySquare(offsetX: 110, offsetY: 20)
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                ForEach(mySquares, id: \.self) { mySquare in
                    MySquareView()
                        .offset(x: mySquare.offsetX, y: mySquare.offsetY)
                }
            }
            .scaleEffect(0.8)

        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it still do it when you remove the call to toggle rotateSquare?

Comment: @WarrenBurton no, if you remove the toggle to rotateSquare there seems to be no memory leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be related to embedding mutation inside a ForEach, which looking at the memory graphs may involve List (which also [seems to have a memory leak when its elements are mutated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58067377/swiftui-possible-memory-leak)). I recommend opening a Feedback on this.

It can be eliminated by removing the ForEach:

```
func square(at offset: Int) -> some View {
    let mySquare = mySquares[offset]
    return MySquareView()
        .offset(x: mySquare.offsetX,
                y: mySquare.offsetY)
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ZStack {
            square(at: 0)
            square(at: 1)
            square(at: 2)
            square(at: 3)
        }
        .scaleEffect(0.8)
    }
}
```

You can also hack your way around this by injecting a recursive AnyView rather than using ForEach. There may be other clever solutions like this; it may be worth exploring further, since losing both ForEach and List is quite obnoxious.

```
func loopOver<C: Collection, V: View>(_ list: C, content: (C.Element) -> V) -> AnyView
{
    guard let element = list.first else { return AnyView(EmptyView()) }
    return AnyView(Group {
        content(element)
        loopOver(list.dropFirst(), content: content)
    })
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ZStack {
            loopOver(mySquares) { MySquareView().offset(x: $0.offsetX, y: $0.offsetY )}
        }
        .scaleEffect(0.8)
    }
}
```

(Using AnyView like this will get in the way of various SwiftUI optimizations, so it's a last resort, but in this case it is likely necessary.)

Comment: Thanks for this, good to know this relates to the ForEach. For now I've made sure to apply most of the modifiers within the ForEach loop and not in child views or outside the ForEach element and most modifiers work.